# Yii2 $session->setId() not working

Tags: session, cookies, authentication, yii2

I'm using Ajax to log in a user from subdomain. The Yii2 app is on another subdomain. Both subdomains are configured to use same cookie and session domains and save paths. I'm including session ID with Ajax call to write the user information to the same session used by non-app subdomain like this:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();
$session->setId($post["session"]);
$session["user.id"] = $user->id;

echo $session->id; // This does not return the same ID originating from post!
```

Unfortunately the user information IS NOT written to the session already existing, but a new one. Is there a session involved somewhere in the middle of login process or why isn't it working? I've also tried `session_id($post["session"])`, but nothing.

This was actually working on previous domain, so I must be missing something. All of the AJAX posted info is correct and checked, the user is logged in properly (checked the logs) but into wrong session.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`yii\web\Session::setId()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#setId()-detail) is a wrapper for [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php), you should read PHP documentation about this function :

> **`string session_id([ string $id ])`**
>
> If `id` is specified, it will replace the current session id. `session_id()` needs to be called before `session_start()` for that purpose.

So you should simply try :

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->setId($customId);
$session->open();
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a little. Indeed now the session file includes the information before login and after login (user details), which didn't happen before, BUT it still writes the session in new file with completely different ID. Any ideas?

Comment: For example, `$oldId = session_id(); $session = Yii::$app->session; $session->setId($oldId); $session->open(); $session->set("oldId", $oldId);`. Then I can really see that session stores the proper old ID, but for some reason it doesn't use the old ID for session ID, just takes a new one.

Comment: Ok, got it. Had to assign the `session_id()` after `$user->login()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think you are following the correct way to `SET` & `GET` session.

Try This:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;
$session->open();
$session->set('id', $post["session"]);
echo $session->get('id');
```

For more info, please click [Session Management - Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not change the result. `$session->set()` adds a session variable. I need to change the session's id itself, which, according to manual should be possible via `$session->setId()`. Latter was working on my previous server, so I'm on right track, I'm just missing something...